# Xcode 6 Swift cannot input into textfield on scrollview

Tags: ios, swift, scrollview, xcode6, textfield

This is my first time doing Xcode swift project, so please bear with me. I am trying to add a scroll view onto my input page. But after putting the text field on the scroll view, I cannot input anything on the text field any more. Please help me.

```
import UIKit

class AddInfoViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!

var containerView2: UIView!

@IBOutlet var test2: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var test1: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let containerSize = CGSize(width: 300.0, height: 1000.0)
    containerView2 = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size:containerSize))
    scrollView.addSubview(containerView2)

  //set up the minimum & maximum zoom scales
    let scrollViewFrame = scrollView.frame
    let scaleWidth = scrollViewFrame.size.width / scrollView.contentSize.width
    let scaleHeight = scrollViewFrame.size.height / scrollView.contentSize.height
    let minScale = min(scaleWidth, scaleHeight)

    scrollView.minimumZoomScale = minScale
    scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 1.0
    scrollView.zoomScale = 1.0

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your ScrollView is covering all the things on your ViewController Like this way :

[image]

And you have to arrange it like this :

[image]

May be this can help you.

Comment: But in this way, my scroll view stops working now. Before changing to your way, I had all the text fields embedded in the scroll view to make it work. Please advise what I did wrong.

Comment: With this way can you Input into your TextField?

Comment: Yes, I can input into the textfield. But the scrollview stopped working too.

Comment: I think you have another Issue...try to find solution.

Answer (score 0):

Are You Adding textField in storyboard or programmatically?

i think if you are adding **scrollView Programmatically** Then You also have to **add textfield Programmatically**! Or ScrollView Override UITextField Objects in storyBoard!

### **///////// if You Are Adding Scroll View in Xib ////////////////**

in xib Click on "Show Document Outline"(on left Bottom Corner)!
Check

```
View
   ScrollView
     Round Style Text Field
     Round Style Text Field
```

This shows that Your textField Are on ScrollView!

if You have it like this

```
View
  Round Style Text Field
  Round Style Text Field
  ScrollView
```

Then Your TextField Are Override By Scroll View!

Comment: Mine is like the first structure, where the text fields are on the scroll view. I added those from the storyboard view and linked to the swift file.

Comment: are you adding scrollView on storyboard or programmatically??

Comment: I did it on storyboard.